# Logging client side events/errors to server

Tags: angularjs

I know people have probably asked this question before, but i have an additional use case. I want to track some particular events on my website, like user clicked on a particular button, or something like user opened this webpage, and log this on my server. How can i do that?
Also I don't want to flood my server with the log requests so any optimization I should keep in mind?
I am working with AngularJS framework.

Thanks

Comment: Use Google Analytics. That's what it is for.

Comment: Actually i am working with kibana, and my client is kibana host, so should i still use google analytics?

Comment: Client side errors are easy. It can be done uisng the $exceptionHandler provider.

Comment: yes, but that only logs errors, for events, what should i do?